Bathroom switch showing odd voltage
Vanity light suddenly quit working.
Bought new vanity light.
Wired it.
New light doesn’t work.
Checked voltage at light.
With switch turned on and breaker on, voltage reading at light: 24
Moved attention to switch.
Double gang box.
Box is a mess (not my work).
Two single pole switches (one for vanity light; one for shower light).
Pigtail from vanity light switch to shower light switch.
Continuity is good.
Switches are not grounded.
With breaker on, voltage reading: 39 on both switches.
Even with that voltage reading, the shower light switch works perfectly.
I have not checked voltage of shower light fixture.
Changed out the vanity light switch.
Continuity good.
Still not working.
Voltage continues to read 39.
(Grounded outlet just below double gang box voltage reading: 122).
I’m open to any feedback.
Thanks in advance.


lost neutral could do that

Get rid of any backstab connections, they are known problems. Then check the neutral wires as well.
